# How to suppress Interactive Broker error warnings Jupyter, Python

Tags: python, jupyter, interactive-brokers, tws

In a Jupyter notebook, I am trying to suppress Error 200 messages from the Interactive Broker's TWS API, such as the following:

Error 200, reqId 12755: No security definition has been found for the request, contract: Option(symbol='SPY', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20210721', strike=407.5, right='P', exchange='SMART')

Error 200, reqId 12761: No security definition has been found for the request, contract: Option(symbol='SPY', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20210721', strike=412.5, right='P', exchange='SMART')

I have used the following code to no avail:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

or

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress messages with a specific code by writing your own error handling routine. This callback method checks the code and only prints messages that aren't Error 200:

```
@iswrapper
def error(self, req_id, code, msg):
    if code != 200:
        print('Error {} for request {}: {}'.format(code, req_id, msg))
```

Comment: Is there any way to implement this in a Jupyter notebook? I’m using ib_insync for my interaction with the API.

Comment: The `error` method is provided by the [EWrapper](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/interfaceIBApi_1_1EWrapper.html) class. I'm sure someone using ib_insync has written a custom `error` callback.